# Grass GIS 6.4.3, How to create a .PTS file

Tags: raster, grass-gis, export, xyz

I'm trying to export a raster map in order to use it in the Flo-2d program.
This program needs a `.pts` DTM file, do you know how I can create it?

Alternatively, I can use a `XYZ` file looking like this one:

```
6413334.59 1936112.79 81.81
6413388.62 1936112.00 81.57
6413500.78 1936108.47 81.29
...........
```

but if I use the `r.out.xyz` command, I get a confused file, looking like an endless row in which the x value is fixed, while the y and z ones changes.

I hope I made it clear, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found out that the file produced by Grass was fine, I just visualized it wrongly using Windows notepad. When I open it with xemacs, the problem doesn't exist! But still, The file produced by Grass can't be opened by the Flo-2D program, and I still can't figure out why :( Thanks for your support! Chiara

Answer (score 2):

With [r.out.xyz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.xyz.html), you can fix the separator:

- with comma

[image]

with this example

```
r.out.xyz input=test10-3-250@testresolution output=/Users/Shared/testexport.txt fs=,
```

and the result is:

[image]

- with space(s) as you want

[image]

with this example

```
r.out.xyz input=test10-3-250@testresolution output=/Users/Shared/testexport2.txt fs=
```

and the result is:

[image]

but the most important is:

> This module, as all GRASS raster modules, will export cells based on the current region settings.

So fix the region with [g.region()](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html) before to match the raster map or a portion of the raster, or...

[image]

```
g.region rast=test10-3-250@testresolution
```

Answer (score 0):

A valide alternative of GRASS GIS `r.out.xyz` is [**gdal_translate**](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif output.xyz
```